# Computing $\epsilon$-packing sets in Euclidean space

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, computer-science, computational-geometry

Let $\epsilon > 0$. For $P\subset \mathbb R^d$, a subset $Q\subset P$ is called an *$\epsilon$-packing* if:

1. for every $p \in P$ there is a $q\in Q$ such that $d(p,q) \leq \epsilon$, and
2. for every $q, q' \in Q$, we have $d(q,q') \geq \epsilon$.
   (See also the definitions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delone_set)).

**Question.** What algorithms exist for computing a maximal $\epsilon$-packing of, e.g., a Euclidean sphere $S^{d-1}\subset \mathbb R^d$?

I did some Googling and have only came up with algorithms for computing packings, coverings, nets, etc., in *finite* metric spaces, e.g., in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0409057).

But how does computing such sets work for continuous subsets of Euclidean space? Do we first need to replace the set with some finite model, or can it be done directly?

Comment: Consider question" Is every P is $\epsilon$  -packable"

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/165502/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).  If anyone would like to answer, I suggest answering over there, to keep all responses on the same site.